# Zero knowledge of two factor

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, factoring, verifiability

[Here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24640/blum-primes-x-3mod-4-zero-knowledge-proof) I overconfident in myself state that I can show, that n has two factors.

This is not completely true, can possibly show $n$ is composite - prover generates RSA key with modulo $n$, and gives $e$ to verifier.

Verifier takes random number $x$, and checks if $x^{e*d}=x$, where $d*e=1$ (mod  $n-1$). If it is, then $n$ is prime, if not $n$ is composite and has factors.

Verifier sends $x^e$ to prover, and if prover sends back $x$ we can be sure that prover has factors of $n$. This doesnt, however garanties that there is just two factors.

How to prove-verify that there is only two factors in $n$?

UPDATE: This is not zeroproof, it is interactive here as was pointed in comments. Well, then. Question becomes more broader - can (duh) show that $n$ is not a prime. How to show it has two factors, zero knowledge, without interactivity?

Comment: "This doesnt, however garanties that there is just two factors." It's also not zero knowledge: a simulator without access to the prover would be unable to compute $x$.

Comment: yea, had a feeling i miss interactivity here, thanks

Comment: Actually, there is no need for a ZKP that $n$ is not prime; anyone can verify that directly in polynomial time.

Comment: yes, but to show that there is no more, no less than two factors?

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly, convince the verifier that $n$ is not a prime number. (*Prime is in P*)
2. Use Zero-Knowledge Proof to make sure that $n$ has no square factor (no $p^2|n$)

   See this paper [Practical zero-knowledge proofs: Giving hints and using deficiencies](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2693062_Practical_Zero-Knowledge_Proofs_Giving_Hints_and_Using_Deficiencies) for details.
3. Showing that $n$ has exactly two factors: if not, the number of quadratic residues is roughly less than $1/8*n$. Verifier just randomly chooses a value y and ask prover to prove whether y is quadratic residue.

   If the probability is roughly $1/4$, then accept.
   Verifier can't cheat since he can only compute the quadratic residue, and let the probability raise, but not decrease below $1/8$.

Comment: How one does the 1.

Comment: Since it's in P, the simulator of zero-knowledge proof can perfectly simulate step 1. But step 3 is incorrect. Zero-knowledge proof requires if it's true, then verifier can accept it with probability 1, but in my proof, we can only do it with high probability.

Comment: this is not zero knowledge, verifier learns if y is quqdratic residue for many y